# How to use DocumentReference in firestore query

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Database with two collections, one is called "shops" and the other is called "groups".
In the "shops" collection, there are some documents that represent different shops in a city and in the "groups" collection there is a document with a single field that is an array of reference.
In the array, I saved the last 20 shops that were inserted in the "shops" collection.

I don't know how to get the documents by the reference save in the array.

My method needs to return a `Stream<List<Shop>>`, I need an idea to resolve my problem, I don't want to use a field in shops' document to save the time when it was inserted.

Comment: you can get the both collection from Firestore and you can manually check shop is available in groups or not and base on that you can filter.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya when I wrote this question I know that a way to resolve my problem could be your idea. I want to know if there are some best ways to get my documents or not, probably I will use your idea.